# What is this character used for: 夰

Tags: meaning

I'm a relative beginner in Chinese. I was trying to draw the character 乔, but missed one stroke and instead got 夰. I was trying to find the meaning of this character before I realised my mistake. I was surprised how little information there is about this character. Several dictionaries don't even contain this character, and Pleco tells me that the pinyin for this character is gao3 but does not give any definition. It is in the basic block of CJK unified ideographs (5930), and appears in the Kangxi dictionary. Are there lots of these characters which have no definition given in English and how would they be used? What does or did this character mean?

Comment: You could just ignore it since it is rarely used.

Comment: Don't bother finding the meaning of that character. I'm a native Chinese but never saw this wierd character before. I assure 99.99 percent Chinese dont know neither(At least in mainland China).

Answer (score 1):

Most people probably wouldn't know (or have even ever seen) the character 夰, before, but anyway.

**汉语大词典**

> hào
>
> 1 同“昊”。天。
>
> 北周  卫元嵩 《元包经·太阴》
>
> 雲浮于夰。
>
> 李江 注
>
> 夰, 天。
>
> 按, 《广韵·上晧》
>
> 夰, 《説文》：‘放也。’昊天字從此。
>
> 2 气。
>
> 北周  卫元嵩 《元包经·太阴》
>
> 夰入于囦, 回浮于元。
>
> 苏渊明 传
>
> 夰入于囦, 天氣降也。
>
> 李江 注
>
> 夰, 氣。

So, for #1 夰 means the same as 昊 - namely "sky/heavens" & #2 gas/air

Comment: btw 汉语大词典 can be purchased in Pleco, it covers the majority of characters